# Moving Files: Matching Partial File/Directory Criteria (lastName, firstName) - Glob, Shutil

Tags: python, glob

**EDIT: ANSWER** Below is the answer to the question. I will leave all subsequent text there just to show you how difficult I made such an easy task..

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

base = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients"

for file in Path("C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans").iterdir():
    name = file.stem.split('-')[0].rstrip()
    subdir = Path(base, name)

        if subdir.exists():
    dest = Path(subdir, file.name)
        shutil.move(file, dest)
```

---

**Preface:**
I'm trying to write code that will move hundreds of PDF files from a :/Scans folder into another directory based on the matching client's name. This question is linked below - a very kind person, Elis Byberi, helped assist me in correcting my original code. I'm encountering another problem though..

To see our discussion and a similar question discussed:

[-Python- Move All PDF Files in Folder to NewDirectory Based on Matching Names, Using Glob or Shutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703454/python-move-all-pdf-files-in-folder-to-newdirectory-based-on-matching-names-u)

[Python move files from directories that match given criteria to new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381446/python-move-files-from-directories-that-match-given-criteria-to-new-directory)

**Question:** How can you move all of the named files in :/Scans to their appropriately matched folder in :/Clients.

**Background:** Here is a breakdown of my file folders to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Within :/Scans folder I have thousands of PDF files, manually renamed (I tried writing a program to auto-rename.. didn't work) based on client and content, such that the folder encloses PDFs labeled as follows:

lastName, firstName - [contentVariable]

(repeat the above 100,000x)

Within the :/C drive of my computer I have a folder named 'Clients' with sub-folders for each and every client, named similar to the pattern above, as 'lastName, firstName'

**EDIT:** The code below will move the entire Scans folder to the Clients folder, which is close, but not exactly what I need to be doing. I only need to move the files within Scans to the corresponding Client fold names.

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

source = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans"
dest = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients"
os.chdir("C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients")

pattern = '*,*'
for x in glob.glob(pattern):
    fileName = os.path.join(source, x)
    print(fileName)
    shutil.move(source, dest)
```

**EDIT [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLIpC.png) - CLOSE!:** The code below will move all the files in Scans to the Clients folder, which is close, but not exactly what I need to be doing. I need to get each file into the correct corresponding file folder within the Clients folder.

This is a step forward from moving the entire Scans folder I would think.

```
source = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans"
dest = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients"

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        shutil.move(path.join(dirpath,file), dest)
```

---

I have the following code below as well, and I am aware it does not do what I want it to do, so I am definitely missing something..

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

path = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirs:
   print(file)

dest_dir = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients/{^w, $w}?"
for file in glob.glob(r'C:Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients/{^w, $w}?'):
    print(file)
    shutil.move(file, dest_dir)
```

1) Should I use os.scandir instead of os.listdir ?

2) Am I moving in the correct direction if I modify the code as such:

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

path = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans"
dirs = os.scandir(path)

for file in dirs:
   print(file)

dest_dir = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients/*"
for file in glob.glob(r'C:Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients, *'):
    dest_dir = os.path.join(file, glob.glob)
    shutil.move(file, dest_dir)
```

Note within the 'for file in glob.glob(r'C:Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients/{^w, $w}?' I have tried replacing 'Clients/{^w, $w}?' with just 'Clients/*'

For the above, I only need the file in :/Scans, written as, "lastName, firstName - [content]" to be matched and moved to /Clients/[lastName, firstName] --- the [content] does not matter. But there are both greedy and nongreedy expressions... which is why I'm unsure about using * or {^w, $w}? -- because we have clients with the same last names, but different first names.

The following error is generated when running the first command:

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1soaR.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLIpC.png)

The following error (though, there is no error?) is generated when running the second command:

[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyAqs.png)

**EDIT/POSSIBLE ANSWER**

Have not yet tested this but, fnmatch(filename, pattern), or, fnmatch.translate(pattern) can be used to test whether the *filename* string matches the *pattern* string, returning **True** or **False**.

From here perhaps you could write a conditional statement..

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        shutil.move(source, destination)
```

or

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        shutil.move(file.join(eachFile, source), destination)
```

I have not tested the two aforesaid codes. I have no idea if they work, but editing allows others to see how my train of thought is progressing.

Comment: Thoughts on using regex = fnmatch.translate('*') with re.match(pattern, string) ?